# another way of "I was 28"

Tags: writing

I want to say I have experiencing as VP of company A when I was 28. Can I say in the other way as "at my 28"?

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not accepted in English. The form is always (to be) (time period) old, and can be shortened in a mostly formal fashion to (to be) (number of years).

Examples:

> The baby is just a few hours old.
>   Kaitlyn here is 15 months old.

(note: babies are referred to as x months old until the age of 2, and sometimes 3. It's also pretty common to use weeks within the first two or three months.)

> When I was 24 years old, I took my savings and left for college.

When you are talking about either anyone in general, or someone not well known to the people you're speaking to, there is an alternate form which makes the age a noun or adjective. It's the same as above, but hyphenated.

> Life is hard for a 17-year-old.
>   Here we have another letter from a 14-year-old reader named Sally.

Answer (score 2):

You can also say "at the age of 28".I think you meant this expression.

Comment: And this can be shortened to: _at age 28_, or even just _at 28_, if enough other details are provided. For example: _At 28, I became a vice president at Company A_.